# Django-Channels AsyncConsumer not working

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels

using `SyncConsumer` with below code works fine

```
class BackgroundTaskConsumer(SyncConsumer):
    def create_users(self, message):
        number = message['number']
        id = message['id']
        UserFactory.create_batch(number, groups=(id,))
```

But when using `AsyncConsumer` with below code stop working

```
class BackgroundTaskConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def create_users(self, message):
        number = message['number']
        id = message['id']
        await UserFactory.create_batch(number, groups=(id,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to warp databse actions in `database_sync_to_async`.

```py
class BackgroundTaskConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def create_users(self, message):
        number = message['number']
        id = message['id']
        await database_sync_to_async(UserFactory.create_batch)(number, groups=(id,))
```

---

it does seem a little strange in how you use `database_sync_to_async`

the reason you wrap the function you call in the way you do is to ensure it is wrapped before it is called.

in python if you do

```
a = c(b())
```

`b()` is called before `c(..)`.

however `database_sync_to_async` needs to do do a few things **before** and **after** you access the DB.

normally in python you would use a `with contextManager` to do this, but this is not compatible with converting from `async` to `sync`.

so by `wrapping` your `UserFactory.create_batch` method this then returns a new method that you can call with `create_batch`. This is working just the same as an `@decorator`

Comment: Thanks. Working. Can you explain why parameters `number, groups=(id,)` outside of `database_sync_to_async`